# How do I access files in the partition that Ubuntu is installed on?

Tags: partitioning

I have two partitions:

- partition C:/ is where Windows is installed, and
- partition D:/ is where Ubuntu is installed.

However there is still free space in D:/ partition that I can access with Windows and save files there. I am unable to access those files that are saved in the same partition as Ubuntu (that is partition D:/). (I can access files in C:/ partition from Ubuntu)

The partition where Ubuntu is installed has more free space. From Windows, partition D:/ looks like this D:/Ubuntu, D:/other_staff well from Ubuntu I am unable to access that other_staff.

Comment: I don't understanded what you want: 1) to access Ubuntu files from Windows; 2) to access D: Windows file from Ubuntu. Which one?

Answer (score 1):

Whiles in ubuntu, open the filesystem drive and open the folder named 'host'. That is where all your other files and folders on that same partition are. Enjoy.